# Как использовать javascript в проекте визуальной веб части asp.net SharePoint

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, sharepoint

В проекте визуальной веб части для SharePoint, я могу создавать файлы содержащие javascript, см рисунок:
[image: Проект с папкой для javascript и файлом содержащим скрипт]

Вопрос: как использовать данный скрипт в коде для:

1. Выполнения на стороне клиента по нажатию кнопки (проверка правильности заполнения формы)
2. Выполнения на стороне клиента для выведения сообщения по завершению действия на сервере?

На текущий момент я в коде, на стороне сервера внедряю javascript после загрузки, соответственно это заставляет меня использовать string переменные, что и не удобно и не правильно. Хотелось бы понять, как работать с этим, и как правильно.

Comment: О чём идет речь? Какой string? Зачем внедрять после загрузки? В форму `<script src=` добавили, файл js к манифесту прикрепили, в каб завернули - всё. Использовать точно так же как и в обычном html или aspx без SharePoint.

Comment: @nick_n_a в какую форму? И о каком манифесте идет речь?

Comment: @nick_n_a все же не совсем верно вы оставили в комментарии подсказку, хотя если создать js файл и выложить его в SharePoint, то он будет работать, однако возникает множество проблем, в конце концов, я нашел ответ и поделился им.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельно файл не будет работать, так как он не разворачивается на сервере SharePoint необходимо использовать модуль:
В нужном месте проекта (будь корневая или иная папка проекта) по правой кнопке жмем "Добавить" --> "Office/SharePoint" -->"Модуль".
Вычищаем от туда все, затем добавляем нужный файл, в моем случае это JavaScript1.js, автоматически создается следующая XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="ScriptPanelButton">
<File Path="ScriptPanelButton\JavaScript1.js" Url="ScriptPanelButton/JavaScript1.js" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

В общем с этим мы уже что-то можем делать, но лучше внести правки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="ScriptPanelButton" Url="Scripts/PanelButtonScripts">
<File Path="ScriptPanelButton\JavaScript1.js" Url="ScriptPanelButton/JavaScript1.js" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

ну а далее в коде, при загрузке панельки:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        string scriptPath = "Scripts/PanelButtonScripts/ScriptPanelButton/JavaScript1.js";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(GetType(), "SHW", scriptPath);
    }
```

отмечу, что на нашем шарике поднят подсайт и в нем создана библиотека вики страниц Scripts, в котору как раз и разворачивается скрипт.
Как итог все заработало очень хорошо!